# Playground shows strange count of execution

Tags: swift-playground

```
let intArray = [5]
intArray.allSatisfy{$0<0} //false, of course, but why 2 times?
```

There is no more operators, as far as I can see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not telling you how many times the block was executed, but rather how many outputs were called on that line. Since the block returns `false` and the function `allSatisfy` returns `false`, that's 2 outputs in 1 line. You'll notice that no matter the size of the array you get the same value, and if you expand the code, i.e.

```
intArray.allSatisfy {
    $0 < 0
}
```

you don't see **2 times**.

Playgrounds doesn't seem to give a counter for executions of closures/functions passed as parameters, rather only for regular for-loops instead.

Comment: >>Playgrounds doesn't seem to give a counter for executions of closures/functions passed as parameters, rather only for regular for-loops instead.
    let intArray = [-10, -23, 6, -10]
    intArray.allSatisfy{
        $0<0 // shows 3 times
    }

Comment: On which Xcode? I'm testing on 10. Also, 3 times sounds weird in that scenario, no?

Comment: Yes, Xcode 10. 3 times - it's OK. Stops immediately on '6' (>0, third number). And yes, code is expanded.